# Weird URL from wallpaper site api

Tags: java, android, api

What does this mean and how can I use it in an android studio app to display wallpapers?

[Using the alpha coders wallpaper api.](https://wall.alphacoders.com/api.php)

URL:

> ```
> "https:\/\/images7.alphacoders.com\/735\/735389.png",
> ```

Comment: I just don't understand what the url is (how it is structured). And if I can't access it how can I use it to view and download images for wallpapers in an android studio app?

Comment: ... Just looks like some poorly escaped String really.

Comment: What is your android programming level? I will try to help you.

Comment: Rather a beginner. I am however familiar with the language. @android_Muncher

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the backslash (`\`) is an escape character when used inside Strings. It appears that particular API uses it on forward slashes although it isn't necessary.

Comment: I see. Removing the backlashes did the job. E.g. https://images7.alphacoders.com/735/735389.png.